# Making a combo box list in the spreadsheet (not in the userform)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a list to my Combobox that's on a spreadsheet. I tried using the code below but nothing happens. I rather not go on properties and fill from what sheet, instead use vba code, just in case there are changes.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Hours")

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Drop Down 1").List = ws.Range("F2:F6").Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind there are two types. One is an Active-X combo box, and the other is a Form combo box, and they act differently.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your object actually is since combobox names use no spaces.
Maybe your are confusing data validation drop downs with acombobox.
But if it's a combobox and you name it without spaces, this will work.

```
Sub add_items()
Set ws = ActiveSheet
        With ws.Drop_Down_1
            For i = 2 To 6
                .AddItem ws.Range("F" & i).Value
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

(VBA novice) Not sure about your specific issue but my combobox doesn't seem to recognize its Change() event when the code is in the Module with the routines it called.  It works when the code is in the same Sheet as the widget.

If anyone knows why, please comment.